# Converting string to int, int to string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working with a WPF file with 2 classes added. I have a Movie class, a Movie Utility class, the MainWindow.xaml, and the MainWindow.xaml.cs. My program is taking questions about a movie, entered in on the .xaml window, and produces a data grid underneath. In the Movie class, I have all of my public strings and dateline's. Like so:

```
namespace FinalExam
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public string movieName { get; set; }

        public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

        public string onDVD { get; set; }

        public string onBluRay { get; set; }

        public string genreType { get; set; }

        public string directorName { get; set; }

        public string producerName { get; set; }

        public int movieLength { get; set; }

        public string moveRating { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs class, all of the strings are called, and the dateline's are converted to string using the ConvertStringToDate syntax.

The problem I'm running into is getting the MovieLength to work. I have it entered as an into but don't know how to go about getting it to show up in the grid without it tripping my boo. Anyway, here's what I have.

```
namespace FinalExam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //GLOBAL VARIABLE AREA
        List<Movie> movieList = new List<Movie>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void but_Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isGoodToAddNewMovie = true;
            Movie newMovie = new Movie();
            newMovie.movieName = txtBox_MovieName.Text;
            newMovie.onDVD = txtBox_DVD.Text;
            newMovie.onBluRay = txtBox_BluRay.Text;
            newMovie.genreType = txtBox_Genre.Text;
            newMovie.directorName = txtBox_Director.Text;
            newMovie.producerName = txtBox_Producer.Text;
            newMovie.moveRating = txtBox_Rating.Text;

            if (MovieUtility.isItDate(txtBox_ReleaseDate.Text))
            {
                newMovie.releaseDate = MovieUtility.ConvertStringToDate(txtBox_ReleaseDate.Text);
                txtBox_ReleaseDate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
            else
            {
                txtBox_ReleaseDate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                isGoodToAddNewMovie = false;
            }

            if (MovieUtility.isItDate(txtBox_Length.Text))
            {
                newMovie.movieLength = MovieUtility.ConvertStringToDate(txtBox_Length.Text);
                txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
            else
            {
                txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter movie length in minutes.");
                isGoodToAddNewMovie = false;
            }

            //ADD PERSON TO LIST
            if (isGoodToAddNewMovie)
            {
                movieList.Add(newMovie);
                dataGrid_Movies.ItemsSource = new List<Movie>(movieList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the issue:

```
if (MovieUtility.isItDate(txtBox_Length.Text))
{
    newMovie.movieLength = MovieUtility.ConvertStringToDate(txtBox_Length.Text);
    txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}
```

Comment: I know that it shouldn't be isItDate or ConvertStringToDate but I couldn't figure out what syntax to use so I just left it like it was for the sake of consistency.

Comment: That was the method that I did post, I attempted the converting to int but it was unsuccessful. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: definition/method signature of `ConvertStringToDate()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to parse the value as an `int`, not `DateTime`. You can test the value first, by using `int.TryParse`, which returns `true` if the value is a valid integer:

```
int length;

if (int.TryParse(txtBox_Length.Text, out length))
{
    newMovie.movieLength = length;
    txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}
else
{
    txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter movie length in minutes.");
    isGoodToAddNewMovie = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did trick!

Comment: @KevinWare, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  When solution is found, check it so other uses know it is no longer an open item.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (Int32.TryParse(txtBox_Length.Text, out newMovie.movieLength))
{
    txtBox_Length.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}
```